# Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':react-native-version-check']

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I've implemented the VersionCheck for react-native, done the setup from the documentation itself, but getting error while running the app.

**Error** `Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':react-native-version-check'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

Implementing for Android
RN Version: 0.72.7
Package: react-native-version-check: ^3.4.7

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by updating **compile** with **implementation** inside `dependencies (android/app/build.gradle)`

old: `compile project(':react-native-version-check')`
new `implementation project(':react-native-version-check')`